# CTL-480 and Ubuntu 14.10 LTS

Tags: 14.10, wacom

I have a CTL-480 Wacom tablet, and I can "use it", I mean, it detects the pen entry and the contact, but when I enter the wacom config on the system preferences, it says that no wacom tablet was detected. The buttons on the top of the tablet and the switch for hand entry doesn't work either. What can I do?

I have it plugged by USB

Comment: 14.10 is not an LTS release. It is, in fact, End of Life and no longer supported. Are you actually using 14.10?

Comment: When I downloaded it, it said LTS. How do I check the version I'm using?

Comment: in fact seems like that I'm using 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the exact same tablet as you, and from my experience i can tell you that everything (Even pressure) works flawlessly, even though it doesn't show up on the system preferences.
Maybe the drivers don't fully support it (Yet).

I strongly recommend you to take a look at the [LinuxWacom wiki on SourceForge](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), as it holds a lot of good information you can use to get your tablet working.

PS: Sorry if this doesn't fully answer your question, i would post this as a comment, but i don't have enough rep to that yet.